# closedness on banach spaces

Tags: operator-theory, banach-spaces

If $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ are banach spaces and $T$ is a bounded linear operator from $X$ to $Y$ such that $T(X)$ is closed in $Y$ and $S$ is a bounded linear operator from $Y$ to $Z$ such that $S(Y)$ is closed in $Z$. Now $S\circ T$ is a bounded linear operator from $X$ to $Z$.

I want to prove that $(S\circ T)(X)$ is closed in $Z$.

Comment: $T(X)=Y$ is closed so $S(T(X))=S(Y)$ closed.

Comment: How can we conclude T(X)=Y. here T is not given to be onto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to prove that for every closed subset $W$ of $Y$ ,$S(W)$ is complete (closed).now to prove $S(W)$ is complete 
let us take a cauchy sequence in $S(W)$
now $S(x_n)$ is cauchy so $x_n$ is cauchy in $W$
now $W$ is complete so $x_n$ converges in $W$, Now
$S$ is bounded operator so $Sx_n$ converges to $Sx$ 
hence $S(W)$ is complete hence closed.

Comment: Probably not a good idea to use the same symbol $Z$ for two different meanings...

Comment: Thanks@user3313320

Comment: How do you deduce that $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a Cauchy sequence form the fact that $(S(x_n))_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a Cauchy sequence?

Comment: because $S(x_n)$ is cauchy sequence so
$\parallel S(x_n)-S(x_m) \parallel$ <$\epsilon$ $\forall$ n,m$\geqslant$N
Now $S$ is bounded operator so 
$\parallel x_n-x_m \parallel$ <$\epsilon/{\parallel S \parallel}$ $\forall$ n,m$\geqslant$N
Hence $x_n$ is cauchy sequence